# Change select element option with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, select-options

I search a lot and no code works for this problem.

I have a select element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clientbutton').click(function(e) {
        $("input#citycode").value(example :2);
    }
}

<select id="citycode">
    <option value="1">city 1</option>
    <option value="2">city 2</option>
    <option value="3">city 3</option>
</select>
```

But I can't change it with javascript on the client side. I try many other solution in Stackoverflow, but none of them worked.

Comment: Where’s the `<button>` with the `id=“clientbutton”`? You have no `<input>` with `id=“citycode”`, so why would you expect this to work?

Comment: I just gave an example

Comment: I lowered the details for simplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
$("#citycode").value(example :2);
```

to

```
$("#citycode").val(2);
```

Supposed you have an element with id `clientbutton`.

Update: `#citycode` is a `select` element, not a `input` element. David Thomas is right.

Comment: Really? You may want to look at the HTML again.

Comment: I just gave an example .I lowered the details for simplicity

Comment: i write example for like 2 men.i know it should like $("#citycode").val(2); and its not work like this.the main problem is not with code .the select wont change easily with just $("#citycode").val(2); ok?other input work but not the "select"

Comment: Then don't write `input#citycode` (which does not exists), but `#citycode` (or `select#citycode` if you like). See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/urukai/xpvt214o/976696/